# p and q are safe primes and with 1000 digits. Argue for or against if its easy on a Laptop to solve RSA-problem using Fermat's factorization method

Tags: cryptography

Question: p and q are safe primes and with 1000 digits. Argue for or against if its easy on a Laptop to solve RSA-problem using Fermat's factorization method.

Answer:

First note that when p and q are approximately of the same size, the have the most secure scenario. Using Fermat's method: Find $(⌊\sqrt{N}⌋+i)^2-N=j^2$ for $i=1,2,3,...$. Then we check if gcd$(i-j,N)$ nontrivial. If $p=2a+1$ and $q=2b+1$, if a and b are primes, we get for some i that gives us a square j: gcd$(i-\sqrt{(⌊\sqrt{(2a+1)(2b+1)}⌋+i)^2-(2a+1)(2b+1)},(2a+1)(2b+1))$

What can I get from this?

Comment: It should be obvious that it is supposed to be hard.  Otherwise RSA would be broken.  You need to show there are so many choices you can't try a reasonable fraction of them.

Comment: You asked a very similar question, where it was mentioned that Fermat only works in practice if the primes are extremely close to each other. This is almost impossible , if we choose them randomly. Of course, eventually Fermat would also work in the other cases, but it would take far too long.

Comment: To make RSA secure, we do not need that $p$ and $q$ have the same number of digits , although this is usually the case. As you mentioned in the link question, we could choose $q$ to have one more digit than $p$. In this case, Fermats method would be utterly useless in practice. But even if the primes have the same number of digits, they need not to be "close" to each other.

Comment: Thankss @Peter!

Comment: How can I do that? @RossMillikan I would like to be able to argue for too

Comment: You base it on how many $1000$ digit numbers there are.  Roughly how far apart would you expect $p$ and $q$ to be?  Certainly not within $10^{100}$ of each other.  That is just too many to try.